# Load thousands of CSV files into tableau

Tags: python, csv, tableau-api

I have a gazillion CSV files and in column 2 is the x-data and column 3 is the y-data. Each CSV file is a different time stamp. The x-data is slightly different in each file, but the number of rows is constant. I'm happy to assume the x-data is in fact identical.

I am persuaded that Tableau is a good interface for me to do some visualization and happily installed tabpy and "voila", I can call python from Tableau... except...  to return an array I will need to return a string with comma separated values for each time stamp, and then one of those strings per x-axis and then.... Hmm, that doesnt sound right.

I tried telling Tableau just open them all and I'd join them later, but gave up after 30 mins of it crunching.

So what do you reckon? I am completely agnostic. Install an SQL server and create a database? Create a big CSV file that has a time-stamp for each column? Google? JSON?

Or maybe there is some clever way in Tableau to loop through the CSV files?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing any data prep outside of Tableau. Since you seem to be familiar with Python, try Pandas to combine all the csv files into one dataframe then output to a database or a single csv. Then connect to that single source.

Comment: Yes, this was more-or-less, what I had in mind, so the question was what best source. I've just found the HYPER format 
and that can be created directly by python and then read automatically by 
Tableau, so maybe that is the "best" source..... https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/extract_api/en-us/help.htm

Comment: I would say that a local hyper file is the quickest source I have worked with. By local I mean not on tableau server because there will be some latency if its hosted. You can create the hyper file much quicker within tableau desktop (10.5 or later). Just create your single source csv file then connect Tableau to it. Within Desktop select the data source then click extract data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, you can combine all the csv files into a single csv, then import that into Tableau. This of course assumes that all of your csv files have the same data structure.

1. Open the command prompt
2. Navigate to the directory where the csv files are (using the `cd` command)
3. Use the command `copy *.csv combined-file.csv`. The combined-file.csv can be whatever name you want.

Comment: Gosh, I hadn't thought of this. So it seems that the copy does an append, so that I would gain a whole bunch of new rows, rather than the extra formats that I had been expecting. But, hm, as you point out, it'd be just one file to open. If that proved tricky to then realign in Tableau then would be easy enough in Excel to sort out.... Maybe the winner....

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried last night. Extremely fast and any future CSV's will automatically tack onto the bottom. Thanks everyone for suggestions.

```
#
#

import os, csv
from tableausdk import *
from tableausdk.HyperExtract import *

basepath = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\242RawFiles"

fpattern = "Well_242"

tableau_filename = "BigData.hyper"

ExtractAPI.initialize()

extract = Extract( tableau_filename )

if ( not extract.hasTable( 'Extract' ) ):
    schema = TableDefinition()
    schema.setDefaultCollation( Collation.EN_GB )
    schema.addColumn( 'Datafile',   Type.CHAR_STRING ) 
    schema.addColumn( 'Solenoid',   Type.DOUBLE ) 
    schema.addColumn( 'Data',       Type.DOUBLE )
    table = extract.addTable( 'Extract', schema )
    if ( table == None ):
        print("Error occurred while creating the table:\nExiting now\n.")
    exit( -1 )
else: 
    table = extract.openTable( 'Extract' )
    if ( table == None ):
         print("Error occurred while opening the table:\nExiting now\n.")
         exit( -1 )
    schema = table.getTableDefinition()

row = Row( schema )

for filename in os.listdir(basepath):

    if (filename.endswith(".csv") and fpattern in filename ):
        with open(basepath+"\\" + filename) as csvfile:
            readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=",")
            readCSV.next()
            for datarow in readCSV:
                row.setCharString( 0, filename[-17:-4] )  #only the tail
                row.setDouble( 1, float(datarow[2]) )  
                row.setDouble( 2, float(datarow[3]) ) 
                table.insert( row )

# Flush the Extract to Disk
extract.close()

# Close the Tableau Extract API
ExtractAPI.cleanup()
```

Comment: Hey @Tunneller 
I am also facing similar situation.
Can u give me little bit more brief on above or any blog???

Comment: Sorry, I just saw this post Nandha. Are you still struggling?

Comment: Hi, I actually dropped my tableau subscription so I don't know if I can duplicate, but I remember how the above worked. I don't know if everyone wants to sit and read our chat, however, is there a way to pm you?